# 89% cpu is ideal but the load average is extremely high in rhel8.4

Tags: load-average

I am using RHEL 8.4 and I seem to always have a very high load average, despite my CPU being 89% idle:

```
$ uname -a
Linux dx11866-hs 4.18.0-305.el8.ppc64le #1 SMP Thu Apr 29 08:53:15 EDT 2021 ppc64le ppc64le ppc64le GNU/Linux

$top
top - 19:32:45 up 150 days,  3:45,  1 user,  load average: 3936.78, 3934.85, 3935.12
Tasks: 819 total,   1 running, 818 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 10.6 us,  0.4 sy,  0.0 ni, 89.1 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem : 377629.6 total, 197139.6 free, 169755.4 used,  10734.7 buff/cache
MiB Swap:  16383.9 total,  12444.2 free,   3939.8 used. 199111.0 avail Mem

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
1271217 yarn      20   0 8059136   5.7g  20608 S 318.8   1.6   6716:49 java
 999164 yarn      20   0   10.3g   3.4g 117376 S 162.5   0.9   2:43.75 java
 997941 yarn      20   0   12.0g   2.1g  71040 S  43.8   0.6   3:28.04 java
     10 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   6.2   0.0  90:45.27 rcu_sched
1000002 yarn      20   0   12.0g 761088  65344 S   6.2   0.2   0:12.84 java
1001197 yarn      20   0   12.0g 752704  65344 S   6.2   0.2   0:11.60 java
1001966 root      20   0   17600   8384   4992 R   6.2   0.0   0:00.02 top
3291901 yarn      20   0 7763072   1.6g  14912 S   6.2   0.4   3027:36 java
4002263 root      20   0 7263168   4.4g  16832 S   6.2   1.2   5859:55 java
      1 root      20   0  181888  19136  10624 S   0.0   0.0  13:50.34 systemd
      2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:19.21 kthreadd
      3 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 rcu_gp
      4 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 rcu_par_gp
      6 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0H-events_highpri
      8 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 mm_percpu_wq
      9 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   3:40.28 ksoftirqd/0
     11 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:11.21 migration/0
     12 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:18.17 watchdog/0
     13 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/0
     14 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/1
     15 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:19.25 watchdog/1
     16 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:11.58 migration/1
     17 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   3:26.51 ksoftirqd/1
     19 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kworker/1:0H-events_highpri
     20 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/2
     21 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:19.18 watchdog/2
     22 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:04.86 migration/2
     23 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   1:54.07 ksoftirqd/2
     25 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kworker/2:0H-events_highpri
     26 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/3
     27 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:18.64 watchdog/3
     28 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:04.53 migration/3

# grep -c proc /proc/cpuinfo
48

 iostat
Linux 4.18.0-305.el8.ppc64le (<hostname>)       11/06/2023      _ppc64le_       (48 CPU)

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
          12.61    0.00    0.64    0.05    0.00   86.70

Device             tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn
nvme0n1           3.59         2.05       171.95   27091032 2268469720
dm-0              0.03         0.14         0.36    1840516    4710876
dm-1              0.03         0.58         1.33    7592176   17510144
dm-2              3.28         0.08       116.26    1036872 1533830064
dm-3              0.53         0.00        40.67      16352  536491196
dm-4              0.00         0.07         0.03     927276     458764
dm-5              0.00         0.00         0.00      18380       5276
dm-6              0.00         0.00         0.00      14660       2084
dm-7              0.32         0.32        13.30    4249592  175458336

iostat -d 5 -x
Linux 4.18.0-305.el8.ppc64le (<hostname>)       11/07/2023      _ppc64le_       (48 CPU)

Device            r/s     w/s     rkB/s     wkB/s   rrqm/s   wrqm/s  %rrqm  %wrqm r_await w_await aqu-sz rareq-sz wareq-sz  svctm  %util
nvme0n1          3.77    7.89    513.41   5294.93     0.02     0.60   0.50   7.05    0.17   22.80   0.18   136.12   671.13   1.22   1.43
dm-0             1.61    0.19    125.55      3.16     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.11    0.29   0.00    77.75    16.84   1.03   0.19
dm-1             0.01    0.00      0.81      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.18    0.00   0.00    65.45     0.00   1.45   0.00
dm-2             0.72    2.95     91.00    295.43     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.21    0.29   0.00   126.23   100.27   1.67   0.61
dm-3             0.15    0.42      9.58     19.93     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.14    0.16   0.00    64.72    47.42   3.54   0.20
dm-4             0.40    0.04     47.73      1.11     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.14    0.16   0.00   119.67    26.24   1.43   0.06
dm-5             0.03    0.00      1.52      0.49     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.07    5.00   0.00    48.03   108.60   2.17   0.01
dm-6             0.07    0.00    126.99      0.47     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.63    0.00   0.00  1866.09   297.71   3.87   0.03
dm-7             0.52    1.13     97.19   4969.42     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.13   14.85   0.02   187.01  4403.33   2.99   0.49

Device            r/s     w/s     rkB/s     wkB/s   rrqm/s   wrqm/s  %rrqm  %wrqm r_await w_await aqu-sz rareq-sz wareq-sz  svctm  %util
nvme0n1          0.20    0.40      1.60     13.60     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     8.00    34.00   6.67   0.40
dm-0             0.20    0.00      1.60      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     8.00     0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-1             0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-2             0.00    0.20      0.00      0.80     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     4.00  10.00   0.20
dm-3             0.00    0.20      0.00     12.80     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00    64.00  10.00   0.20
dm-4             0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-5             0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-6             0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-7             0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00

Device            r/s     w/s     rkB/s     wkB/s   rrqm/s   wrqm/s  %rrqm  %wrqm r_await w_await aqu-sz rareq-sz wareq-sz  svctm  %util
nvme0n1          0.00    9.40      0.00    319.20     0.00     2.60   0.00  21.67    0.00    0.09   0.00     0.00    33.96   1.06   1.00
dm-0             0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-1             0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-2             0.00    6.60      0.00    229.60     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00    34.79   0.91   0.60
dm-3             0.00    4.00      0.00     75.20     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00    18.80   1.00   0.40
dm-4             0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-5             0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-6             0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-7             0.00    1.40      0.00     14.40     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00    10.29   2.86   0.40

Device            r/s     w/s     rkB/s     wkB/s   rrqm/s   wrqm/s  %rrqm  %wrqm r_await w_await aqu-sz rareq-sz wareq-sz  svctm  %util
nvme0n1          0.00    2.20      0.00     84.80     0.00     0.20   0.00   8.33    0.00    0.09   0.00     0.00    38.55   2.73   0.60
dm-0             0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-1             0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-2             0.00    2.20      0.00     72.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00    32.73   1.82   0.40
dm-3             0.00    0.20      0.00     12.80     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00    64.00  10.00   0.20
dm-4             0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-5             0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-6             0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-7             0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00

Device            r/s     w/s     rkB/s     wkB/s   rrqm/s   wrqm/s  %rrqm  %wrqm r_await w_await aqu-sz rareq-sz wareq-sz  svctm  %util
nvme0n1          0.00    0.40      0.00      1.60     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     4.00  10.00   0.40
dm-0             0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-1             0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-2             0.00    0.40      0.00      1.60     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     4.00  10.00   0.40
dm-3             0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-4             0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-5             0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-6             0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-7             0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00

Device            r/s     w/s     rkB/s     wkB/s   rrqm/s   wrqm/s  %rrqm  %wrqm r_await w_await aqu-sz rareq-sz wareq-sz  svctm  %util
nvme0n1          0.00    1.00      0.00     40.00     0.00     0.40   0.00  28.57    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00    40.00   6.00   0.60
dm-0             0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-1             0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-2             0.00    0.40      0.00     13.60     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00    34.00   5.00   0.20
dm-3             0.00    0.20      0.00     12.80     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00    64.00  10.00   0.20
dm-4             0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-5             0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-6             0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-7             0.00    0.80      0.00     13.60     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00    17.00   2.50   0.20

Device            r/s     w/s     rkB/s     wkB/s   rrqm/s   wrqm/s  %rrqm  %wrqm r_await w_await aqu-sz rareq-sz wareq-sz  svctm  %util
nvme0n1          0.00    1.40      0.00     58.40     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.14   0.00     0.00    41.71   4.29   0.60
dm-0             0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-1             0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-2             0.00    1.00      0.00     32.80     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00    32.80   4.00   0.40
dm-3             0.00    0.40      0.00     25.60     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00    64.00   5.00   0.20
dm-4             0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-5             0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-6             0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-7             0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00

Device            r/s     w/s     rkB/s     wkB/s   rrqm/s   wrqm/s  %rrqm  %wrqm r_await w_await aqu-sz rareq-sz wareq-sz  svctm  %util
nvme0n1          0.00    0.80      0.00     27.20     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00    34.00   7.50   0.60
dm-0             0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-1             0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-2             0.00    0.20      0.00      0.80     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     4.00  10.00   0.20
dm-3             0.00    0.20      0.00     12.80     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00    64.00  10.00   0.20
dm-4             0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-5             0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-6             0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-7             0.00    0.40      0.00     13.60     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00    34.00   5.00   0.20

Device            r/s     w/s     rkB/s     wkB/s   rrqm/s   wrqm/s  %rrqm  %wrqm r_await w_await aqu-sz rareq-sz wareq-sz  svctm  %util
nvme0n1          0.00    9.00      0.00    300.00     0.00     2.00   0.00  18.18    0.00    0.09   0.00     0.00    33.33   1.11   1.00
dm-0             0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-1             0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-2             0.00    9.00      0.00    264.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00    29.33   0.67   0.60
dm-3             0.00    1.20      0.00     30.40     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00    25.33   3.33   0.40
dm-4             0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-5             0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-6             0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-7             0.00    0.80      0.00      5.60     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     7.00   2.50   0.20

Device            r/s     w/s     rkB/s     wkB/s   rrqm/s   wrqm/s  %rrqm  %wrqm r_await w_await aqu-sz rareq-sz wareq-sz  svctm  %util
nvme0n1          0.00    1.20      0.00     41.60     0.00     0.20   0.00  14.29    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00    34.67   3.33   0.40
dm-0             0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-1             0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-2             0.00    0.40      0.00     13.60     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00    34.00   5.00   0.20
dm-3             0.00    0.20      0.00     12.80     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00    64.00  10.00   0.20
dm-4             0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-5             0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-6             0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-7             0.00    0.80      0.00     15.20     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00    19.00   2.50   0.20

Device            r/s     w/s     rkB/s     wkB/s   rrqm/s   wrqm/s  %rrqm  %wrqm r_await w_await aqu-sz rareq-sz wareq-sz  svctm  %util
nvme0n1          0.00    2.00      0.00     62.40     0.00     0.80   0.00  28.57    0.00    0.10   0.00     0.00    31.20   3.00   0.60
dm-0             0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-1             0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-2             0.00    1.40      0.00     32.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00    22.86   2.86   0.40
dm-3             0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-4             0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-5             0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-6             0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-7             0.00    1.40      0.00     30.40     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00    21.71   1.43   0.20

Device            r/s     w/s     rkB/s     wkB/s   rrqm/s   wrqm/s  %rrqm  %wrqm r_await w_await aqu-sz rareq-sz wareq-sz  svctm  %util
nvme0n1          0.00    1.40      0.00     63.20     0.00     0.20   0.00  12.50    0.00    0.14   0.00     0.00    45.14   4.29   0.60
dm-0             0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-1             0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-2             0.00    0.80      0.00     39.20     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00    49.00   2.50   0.20
dm-3             0.00    0.20      0.00     12.80     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00    64.00  10.00   0.20
dm-4             0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-5             0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-6             0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-7             0.00    0.60      0.00     11.20     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00    18.67   3.33   0.20

 #lscpu
Architecture:        ppc64le
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              48
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-47
Thread(s) per core:  8
Core(s) per socket:  6
Socket(s):           1
NUMA node(s):        1
Model:               2.0 (pvr 0080 0200)
Model name:          POWER10 (architected), altivec supported
Hypervisor vendor:   pHyp
Virtualization type: para
L1d cache:           32K
L1i cache:           48K
L2 cache:            1024K
L3 cache:            4096K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):   0-47
Physical sockets:    1
Physical chips:      4
Physical cores/chip: 6

# numactl --hardware
available: 1 nodes (0)
node 0 cpus: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47
node 0 size: 379675 MB
node 0 free: 278579 MB
node distances:
node   0
  0:  10

# numastat
                           node0
numa_hit                26144191
numa_miss                      0
numa_foreign                   0
interleave_hit           5660366
local_node              26144191
other_node                     0


How can I identify the bottleneck and how can I fix this?


cat /proc/interrupts output - https://pastebin.com/wjqrYVZm
```

Comment: Is there a problem here? Is the system unresponsive? I suspect you might be reading too much into the load value. Have a look at the answers here: [How can I chose a max load threshold depending on the number of available cores?](https://serverfault.com/q/771233).

Comment: Also. how many cores does this machine have? How many threads? A load value is useless without knowing that. What is the output of `grep -c proc /proc/cpuinfo`? Please [edit] that into your question.

Comment: The system was rebooted once and the RCA from the support was that it happened because of high load average on it.

Comment: That's nonsense. It might have happened because of a high CPU _use_, but not because of the load average.

Comment: [This comment](https://serverfault.com/a/667237/564625) could explain the high load average with low CPU usage - the TL;DR - load average includes tasks blocked on disk IO. Lots of tasks using slow disk (or a disk that can't handle the number of IO requests thrown at it) will increase load average without increasing CPU usage

Comment: Disk is also 86% ideal.

Comment: You apparently have 48 processors, but only 1 task currently running. Are all those processors/cores actually on-line and usable (check `lscpu`)? Also check `/proc/interrupts`: is the interrupt workload distributed in a sensible way across the available cores, taking the system's possible NUMA characteristics into account (see `numactl --hardware`, `numastat`)?

Comment: Try `iostat -d 5 -x` for actual speeds and utilisation. Without arguments it only displays the totals since rebooting.

Comment: cat /proc/interrupts output is huge. How do i share here?

Comment: You might put `/proc/interrupts` into a [pastebin service](https://pastebin.com/) and add a link to your question. But I was mainly interested in one thing: are the non-zero values getting piled onto just one or a small group of CPUs, or are the interrupts getting roughly evenly distributed? The former would suggest a possible bottleneck in interrupt handling.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/wjqrYVZm
top - 16:25:39 up 31 days, 36 min,  1 user,  load average: 642.84, 649.28, 652.51
Tasks: 720 total,   2 running, 718 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 10.3 us,  2.2 sy,  0.0 ni, 85.2 id,  0.6 wa,  0.0 hi,  1.7 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem : 377629.6 total, 217351.7 free, 150073.1 used,  10204.9 buff/cache
MiB Swap:  16383.9 total,  16383.9 free,      0.0 used. 221294.5 avail Mem

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
3866157 yarn      20   0   23.0g   8.7g 100224 S 162.5   2.4  16:19.95 java

Truncated output

Comment: [root@dx11866-hs ~]# numactl --hardware
available: 1 nodes (1)
node 1 cpus: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47
node 1 size: 377629 MB
node 1 free: 233937 MB
node distances:
node   1
  1:  10
[root@dx11866-hs ~]# numastat
                           node1
numa_hit              9562016020
numa_miss                      0
numa_foreign                   0
interleave_hit        4909428945
local_node            9562016023
other_node                     0

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a typical pattern when you have aapplication (particularly a Java application) using a very large number of threads, and something (e.g. database operations or network access) forces the application to serialize.

If the majority of application's threads are waiting for something that cannot be fully expressed as a wait state of the operating system's scheduler, then all the threads will queue for processing, but as soon as it's their turn, most of them will just check what they're waiting for, and will give up their CPU timeslot on this round and go right back to the execution queue again. This can cause the load average values to grow to absurd levels, even though the CPUs actually have plenty of idle time.

This can cause automatic monitoring (or even operations people!) to panic, because such sky-high load values on a traditional computation-intensive workloads would mean the system is hopelessly mired down and not getting much useful work done. But since there is a lot of idle CPU time and plenty of free memory, your workload is clearly neither computation-intensive nor memory-intensive: it must be I/O intensive instead.

A Java VM can exacerbate situations like this: if there are wait states for the Java threads at the JVM level that cannot be directly mapped to corresponding OS-level wait states, then even if the Java code "sleeps", the underlying thread of the JVM needs to keep checking for the wake condition, which will also cause "short-cycling" as above.

In your specific case, 7 out of your top 10 consumers of CPU time are Java processes of user `yarn`. You should drill down into the JVMs, to investigate what the individual threads of each JVM are doing on average, and try and find out what they are waiting for. My first guess would be some sort of database or network operation is holding back some key thread, and then other threads cannot proceed until that key thread can advance.

Unfortunately, this tends to be something that only the application developer can really fix. They might have to find algorithms that can do the required tasks in a lockless manner, and/or make sure their database queries are sensible and that the structure of the database is optimal for the kind of requirements the application will place to it.

Some useful reading: https://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2017-08-08/linux-load-averages.html

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. The workload is indeed IO intensive. GPFS and CDP are running on these nodes with ESS storage being accessed over the 100G network.

Comment: I can see TCP and TCP6 are being used by Java but TCP6 are way more higher than TCP connections.. Could that be the reason for high load average?

Comment: TCP6 (= IPv6-ready TCP networking) might be very slightly more load than the IPv4-only TCP version, but it is usually negligible or at most a very small part of the problem.